# Real-time monitoring script for apache with only specific fields listed

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, logging, realtime

I am real-time monitoring my website log, but would like to create a script that shows only the following in nice pretty columns.

log being used: /var/log/httpd/access_log (default log file and settings)

Host Name - IP Address - Page - Date & Time

Current command being used via Terminal: tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log | awk '{ print "hostname" $1 $7 $4 }'

I have found someone that created what i am trying to do, but they have not responded to me. Here is screen shot of what i would like to end up with

http://qph.cf.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-fde4d84bf459d14aff0ef930e4f8c7fe

Also would like to incorporate netstat -anp | grep :80 | wc -l into the script at the top to show current connection count

My current output is garbled as shown below:

IPPAGETIME

with no separations etc...

I am new to scripting in general so this is all new to me and took me a bit to get awk to work for me, if there is a post with this already please share

```
    #!/bin/sh

    # Define some variables#
    TAIL="/usr/bin/tail -f"
    # TAIL command can also be -10, -15, -20, -30
    LOG="/var/log/httpd/access_log"
    TOTAL=`netstat -pant | grep :80 | wc -l`
    TOTAL2=`netstat -pant | grep :443 | wc -l`
    echo "There are $TOTAL port 80 connections."
    echo "There are $TOTAL2 port 443 connections."
    uptime | awk '{print $8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15}'

    #Let's do it#
    $TAIL $LOG | awk '{print$3 " " $8 " " $4 " " $6 " " $8 " " $9 " " $7}'

    #DONE
```

Comment: What have you tried?  You do not specify what your 'real-time monitoring' is now.

Comment: tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log | awk '{ print "hostname" $1 $7 $4 }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stephan fancy putting the link to the original question?

user157574

You will want to use printf or tput with column most likely. Using these works for me, although I realise it is not real time:

```
less access_log | grep 05/Feb/2013 | awk '{print $1,$4,$7;}'

less access_log | grep 05/Feb/2013 | awk '{ x = $2 " " $4 " " $7 ; printf "%-15s %-20s \n", $1, x, $7}'
```

Edit:

You can try a changed version of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ACCESSLOG="/var/log/apache2/access_log"
TOTAL=`netstat -pant | grep :80 | wc -l`

echo "There are a total of $TOTAL port 80 connections."
uptime | awk '{print $8,$9,$10,$11,$12}'

tail -5 $ACCESSLOG | grep "05/Feb/2013" | awk '{ x = $2 " " $4 " " $7 ; printf "%-15s %-20s \n", $1, x, $7}'
```

You could edit it to either tail -f so it is live or tail -5 , -10 , -20 etc.

Comment: i will give it a try, in the end i am as mentioned in both posts trying to create a shell script

Comment: i am trying to do realtime like the tail -f does, how do i make the above show constantly and not just report once

Comment: combining your awk '{ x = $2 " " $4 " " $7 ; printf "%-15s %-20s %4d\n", $1, x, $7}' with my tail -f access_log got me very close, thank you so much

Comment: i am getting the following IP - TIME DATE - PAGE - 0, what does the 0 at the end mean?

Comment: Remove %4d before \n

Comment: now how to put this into a bash script and how do i add netstat -anp | grep :80 | wc -l to show number of connection? is it possible to also add load?

Comment: I have edited my answer. See above.

Comment: how did you add the - into the lines? i want to add another - between the status code i added and the time, also want to switch the time and IP places, i tried but when i modify the above the dash moves but not the IP or the time or i get a syntax error

Comment: also how do i add it to a bash script that includes netstat -anp | grep :80 | wc -l to show current connection count at the top and runs every 10 sec

Comment: just got your update, holy crap thank you so much, no i can read it and learn from it like i did you AWK line

Comment: so i got a chance to create the bash script, this is a stupid question, it only runs once, should i use watch or at inside the script, watch outside of course

Comment: i used watch -n 2 ./script.sh and after a few edits i have it perfect, wish i could do colors

Comment: What else did you edit within it?

Comment: just added some more fields, took out the grep date since it showed nothing from the log with it added, nothing special

Comment: any idea on how to colorize the results and add in lantency?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I developed an open-source tool (script) to do what you want, called [httpdmon](https://github.com/uuf6429/httpdmon).

It is written in PHP so it is easily customizable (though you're welcome to ask for more features on Github).

Here's a screenshot:

[image: httpdmon in action]